# When does one vector has bigger norm than the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be two *probability* vectors (i.e., with all components $\geq 0$ and summing up to 1). Then I was wondering what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $$\|u\|_p\leq \|v\|_p \quad \forall p\in[1,\infty).$$

I could check that $u_k\leq v_k$ is a sufficient condition, but it need not be necessary.

Comment: Computing the norms of $u, v$ is not hard. I expect the easiest way to see which is bigger will just be to check directly. But if you have some particular *kind* of vectors $u,v$ in mind, maybe there will be some other condition.

Comment: Your question feels a little bit like: "what are necessary and sufficient conditions for when $x < y$, for integers $x,y$?" To which the answer must surely be: just check whether or not $x < y$ is true...

Comment: Sorry If it is not clear even if I write "vectors"...Also I don't think I have asked anything about the computational difficulty of the norms.

Comment: It's just that necessary and sufficient conditions are a funny thing. Every property is a necessary and sufficient condition for itself, so what you really mean when you say "necessary and sufficient condition" is, is there some *other* way of stating this property? But maybe the other way will be trivially equivalent, or maybe it will be far more complicated. Especially when the original condition ($\|u\| \le \|v\|$) is so simple. So it is worth asking yourself, what are you really looking for in terms of a necessary and condition? Often when it comes up in research, what one is really...

Comment: ...looking for is something that is computationally more efficient, i.e. easy to check. So if you're not looking for that then it's unclear what you are looking for, and why you aren't satisfied with just checking whether or not $\|u\| \le \|v\|$. Anyway, now that you've specified probability vectors your question is a little more reasonable than it was before, but it's still not terribly reasonable.

Comment: It's not possible that $u_k < v_k$ for all $k$, because then $u$ and $v$ would not both have components summing up to $1$. So your proposed sufficient condition just reduces to $u = v$.

Comment: Yes, you are right...should I delete that sentence..?

Answer (score 0):

we put $f(x)=\|x\|_p^p$ , $C=\{ x=(x_i)_{i=1}^n\in R^n: x\geq0, \sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1\}$ and $\partial C=\{x\in C : x_i=0 ,\quad for\quad some \quad i=1,...,n\}$. $f(x)$ is strictly convex function on convex set $C$, and it has unique point that is called by $x_*$ which $x_{*i}$ are $\frac{1}{n}$ for each $i=1,...,n$.  for all $x\in \partial C$, $g_x(t)=tx_*+(1-t)x \quad t\in [0,1]$. If both $f(x)>f(y)$ and $\|x-x_*\|_1\leq \|y-x_*\|_1$ are true then At least two points exist such as $x_1,\quad y_1$ such that $\|x_1-x_*\|_1\leq \|y_1-x_*\|_1$ and $f(x_1)=f(y_1)$ . this is Contrary to the assumption with strictly convex function  $f(x)$, because $\nabla f(tx_1+(1-t)y_1).(x_1-y_1)=0, \quad t\in(0,1)$.

However, we show $\|x\|_p\leq\|y\|_p$ if and only if $ \|x-x_*\|_1\leq \|y-x_*\|_1 $. thus $max\{ x_{i} \}_{ i = 1 } ^n \leq max\{ y_{i}\}_{i=1} ^n
$ if and only if $\|x\|_p\leq\|y\|_p$ for every $p\in [1,\infty]$.

Comment: I think you could ask in a question (in another page) whether what you are thinking is correct or not, rather than shooting your random (trivially) wrong ideas. Please don't feel pressurize that you have to answer this question by any means.

Comment: Also it would be great if you delete your wrong answers (which are explained by users why they are wrong, and possibly could not be corrected). BTW, I did not downvote anything.

Answer (score -2):

It can be $ max\{ u_{i} \}_{ i = 1 } ^n \leq max\{ v_{i}\}_{i=1} ^n$.

Proof:

it is clear for $p=1$.

We prove for each $1<p\leq \infty $. We know that $\|.\|_p$ is (strictly for all $p<\infty$) convex function and has an unique minimize on feasible solution ($\{x\in R^n : \Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i=1\} $) which it is common for all $p$. We denote this point with $u^*$. It is clear that if $u$ approch from $v$ via $\|.\|_p  \quad \forall p\in(1,\infty]$ to $u^*$. However, it can be investigated by one of $1<p\leq \infty$.

Comment: No, its not in either direction.

Comment: This is true when $p=\infty$... otherwise, I doubt its truthfulness.  You should consider including at least an outline of a proof for why one of those inequalities should imply $\Vert u\Vert \leq \Vert v\Vert$ for $1<p<\infty$.  Note if $p=1$ then $\Vert u\Vert =\Vert v\Vert=1$.

Comment: Flagged to be closed!